# What is the difference (if any) between REM statements and comments?

Tags: comments

I have recently come across the term REM statement and wondered, is it synonymous with comment?

Comment: REM is used in Windows batch files for comments.  And iirc in some old school BASIC's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REM is a statement in some older BASIC dialects, like for example [in C64 BASIC](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/REM). It starts a comment line. [Even Visual Basic still supports it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zzw0d942.aspx), even though the preferred syntax for comments in Microsoft dialects of BASIC is a single quote since Quick Basic.

Many people in my generation made their first programming experiments in the 80s on Commodore home computers which used a BASIC interpreter as their default command shell, so the term *REM Statement* as a synonym for *comment* might still be engrained in some people. I haven't heard anyone use that term for about 20 years, though.

Answer (score 12):

Strictly REM is a REMark and it is very similar to a comment, however in Windows batch files it will be shown to the user unless either ECHO Off has been called earlier in the file or it is preceded by @ as in:

```
REM This will be shown during execution
@REM This will not!
@ECHO OFF
REM Nor this!
```

So the answer is **nearly** but not quite in batch files.

In `BASIC` it is a comment.